# Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit xbindkeys do not recognize mouse button depression

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, mouse, xbindkeys

I have installed xbindkeys on Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit in order to emulate middle mouse button and my configuration file has the following line:

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'mouseclick 2'"
control + b:1
```

However, when I press control together with the first mouse button middle mouse click is not emulated. I noticed that when I bind it to keyboard keys exclusively there is no problem. Therefore, the problem is that `xbindkeys` do not recognize the mouse buttons. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well I made it work with the following modification:

```
"/usr/bin/xte 'mouseclick 2'"
control + b:1 + release
```

I do not know why this is not the case with keyboard shortcuts but for compound shortcuts consisting of keyboard and mouse buttons this is the case.